# Best Practice: Comments regarding an old version of an answer

Tags: discussion, edits, comments

Someone posts a code snippet in an answer.
I point out a bug in a comment.
He edits the answer and fixes the bug.
He makes a comment: "@Tim Pohlmann I fixed the bug!"

Should I...
a) ...delete my comment?
Then his comment seems out of place.
b) ...do nothing?
Then my comment seems out of place (especially if people miss his comment).
c) ...do something else?

Comment: Delete yours, mark his as obsolete, done?